# Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку (Python)

Tags: python

**Задача №114175. SMS-голосование**

На телевизионном шоу зрители голосуют за участников шоу, отправляя SMS-сообщение с номером участника. Определите победителя шоу на основе присланных SMS-сообщений.

**Входные данные**

Первая строка входных данных содержит количество участников шоу и количество проголосовавших телезрителей. Во второй строке содержится список номеров, присланных телезрителями, через пробел.

**Выходные данные**

Программа должна вывести номер участника, набравшего наибольшее число голосов. Если таких несколько, то программа должна вывести номера всех победителей шоу в порядке возрастания.
Неверные номера, присланные телезрителями (то есть большие, чем N) необходимо игнорировать.

```
Примеры
входные данные
3 7
1 2 2 1 3 2 3
выходные данные
2
```

Я написала следующее решение.

```
U,N=map(int,input().split())
A=list(map(int,input().split()))
count=[0]*(U+1)
for i in A:
    if i<=U:
        count[i]+=1
m=max(count)
for k in range(1,U+1):
    if m==count[k]:
        print(k,end=" ")
```

Решение проходит все тесты, кроме одного. Возникает >"Ошибка во время выполнения программы"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не учла?

Answer (score 2):

Вы почти все сделали правильно, кроме

> Неверные номера, присланные телезрителями (то есть большие, чем N) необходимо игнорировать.

Во-первых, должно быть "большие, чем U". И я полагаю что это не просто опечатка. Надо проверять не только что они "большие, чем U" но и что они "меньшие, чем 1". Если подать в вашу программу номер участника меньше единицы, она сломается. Как она сломается зависит зависит от номера.

Если передать номер 0, то ошибки не будет. Если передать небольшое отрицательное число, то прибавится единичка к чужому участнику. Например: `count[-1]` означает в нашем случае `count[U]`. Если отрицательный индекс очень мал (`< -U`), то будет ошибка обращения по индексу.

Кажется, это единственная ошибка. Исправить можно так:

```
U,N=map(int,input().split())
A=list(map(int,input().split()))
count=[0]*(U+1)
for i in A:
    if 1<=i<=U: # проверяем номер строго
        count[i]+=1
m=max(count)
for k in range(1,U+1):
    if m==count[k]:
        print(k,end=" ")
```

Более питонический способ использует `collections.Counter` от генератора, который фильтрует значения из СМС. Результаты надо будет отсортировать, так как `collections.Counter` не поддерживает порядок:

```
import collections

u = int(input().split()[0])
count = collections.Counter(v for v in map(int, input().split()) if 1 <= v <= u)
m = max(count)
print(*sorted(v for v, c in count.items() if c == m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал бы для начала сделать вот так:

```
count = {}

for i in A:
    count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1

m = max(count)

print(*[key for key, value in count.items() if value == m])
```

основная проблема, как мне кажется, это заполнение словаря